# Using xdebug in PHP AMQPQueue::consume()

Tags: php, rabbitmq, xdebug, amqp, php-amqp

We are using RabbitMQ and would like to use xdebug inside of a consumer.  We are using `AMQPQueue` to listen for messages on the queue.  I can use xdebug up to `AMQPQueue::consume()` but once `consume()` is called I can not get a breakpoint.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

[`AMQPQueue::consume(callable $callback = null, $flags = AMQP_NOPARAM, $consumerTag = null)`](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/blob/7b5ef84a3c347b1b3ab40f4c1f1f6dde899773ef/stubs/AMQPQueue.php#L116) implemented in C ([amqp_queue.c:816](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/blob/7b5ef84a3c347b1b3ab40f4c1f1f6dde899773ef/amqp_queue.c#L816)) and when new message appears ([amqp_queue.c:908](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/blob/7b5ef84a3c347b1b3ab40f4c1f1f6dde899773ef/amqp_queue.c#L908)) on a channel (in terms of AMQP) calls callback function `$callback` ([amqp_queue.c:963](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/blob/7b5ef84a3c347b1b3ab40f4c1f1f6dde899773ef/amqp_queue.c#L963)). If you set breakpoint inside callback function, xdebug will stop on it when that callback will be called.

Under the hood there are endless loop with blocking socket reading which read everything on a channel and if it a message, pass it to callback. That loop breaks only when some exception happened (incl. in a callback) and when boolean `false` returned.

When no messages are on the channel `consume()` function will be running and blocking main PHP execution thread, so it may looks like application is hanging.

Comment: I have tried this.  But once inside the loop, my breakpoint is not recognized.

Comment: Does xdebug breakpoint works outside that callback? Can you post some example code with breakpoints placement to demonstrate your exact problem?

Comment: I can place a breakpoint outside and if I try to step into the consume() method my debug session freezes.  I can try to post a code sample later but its difficult to do because of the size of the code base.

Comment: See the last sentence in the answer: "When no messages are on the channel consume() function will be running and blocking main PHP execution thread, so it may looks like application is hanging.". Alternatively, add debug output to callback function and run appication in normal mode (no debug) and see whether it get actually called. But first check whether there are any messages in a queue you are consuming from.

Comment: So the way that I tested this was to add a breakpoint to the function I wanted to stop in.  Then I went into our UI and started an action that pushes a message to RabbitMQ.  When the consumer runs, our UI is updated via XMPP.  I could see that the UI would update and the breakpoint was never triggered.  Log statements surrounding the breakpoint ensured that the code with the breakpoint was executed.  Have you ever used a breakpoint with in a RabbitMQ consumer?